# How to change Outlook email item before it openned in VSTO

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin

I try to transmit with the email some service information. Add it to the email body before sending I can. Is there a way to extract and remove this information from MailItem.HtmlBody while email is opening in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the information as soon as items arrive to users mailbox you can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class which is fired  when a new item is received in the Inbox. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, MailItem, MeetingItem, or SharingItem. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item.

Outlook items can be viewed in the inspector and explorer windows.

For explorers you can handle the [SelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869813(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Explorer class which is fired when the user selects a different or additional Microsoft Outlook item programmatically or by interacting with the user interface. This event also occurs when the user (either programmatically or via the user interface) clicks or switches to a different folder that contains items, because Outlook automatically selects the first item in that folder.

For inspectors you may handle the [NewInspector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867841(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Inspectors class which is fired whenever a new inspector window is opened, either as a result of user action or through program code. The event occurs after the new Inspector object is created but before the inspector window appears. So, I'd suggest waiting for the first `Activate` event to get access to the MailItem instance opened.